# How to show total count of elements based on two conditions in react js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, filter, reduce

I am trying to show total count of participants based on two conditions: have `"Nume": "4S110"`  and `"Nume": "Contabilitate"` from `INDICATORI` array and `Cursuri` array.

to show them as

````
const cont = popular.reduce((total, participant) => total + participant.Cursuri
  .filter(curs => curs.Nume === "Contabilitate") && participant.INDICATORI
  .filter(indicator => indicator.Nume === "4S110").length,0)

output is : 0, it should be 1


api is:

```
"rows": [
   {
     "id": "15f806ec-79cf-498f-8a4d-8bc8fdf8c43e",
     "Nume": "negrea",
     "Prenume": "ioana",
     "Varsta": 40,
     "createdAt": "2022-04-27T13:17:05.000Z",
     "updatedAt": "2022-04-27T13:17:05.000Z",
     "deletedAt": null,
     "INDICATORI": [
       {
         "id": "068170b3-7995-41df-8fac-4f2bc577e2c6",
         "Nume": "4S110",
         "importHash": null,
         
       }
     ],
     "Cursuri": [{
         "id": "068170b3-7995-41df-8fac-4f2bc577e2c6",
         "Nume": "Contabilitate",
         "importHash": null,
         ]
   },
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.filter()` function returns an array so you need to add `.length`. `Math.min()` can help in case you want to count such person only once (must have an entry in both items).

```js
let popular = JSON.parse(`[
   {
     "id": "15f806ec-79cf-498f-8a4d-8bc8fdf8c43e",
     "Nume": "negrea",
     "Prenume": "ioana",
     "Varsta": 40,
     "createdAt": "2022-04-27T13:17:05.000Z",
     "updatedAt": "2022-04-27T13:17:05.000Z",
     "deletedAt": null,
     "INDICATORI": [
       {
         "id": "068170b3-7995-41df-8fac-4f2bc577e2c6",
         "Nume": "4S110",
         "importHash": null         
       }
     ],
     "Cursuri": [{
         "id": "068170b3-7995-41df-8fac-4f2bc577e2c6",
         "Nume": "Contabilitate",
         "importHash": null
         }]
   }]`);
   

 
 const count = popular.reduce((total, participant) => total + Math.min(participant.Cursuri
  .filter(indicator => indicator.Nume === "Contabilitate").length, participant.INDICATORI
  .filter(indicator => indicator.Nume === "4S110").length), 0)

 console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thanks  @mickl On my end, is still giving me 0 instead of 1:(

Comment: @CCIBN I think I misunderstood your question initially. Try to use `Math.min()` as in my modified example. I'm assuming participant should be count only once